# Dialogflow firebase fulfillment are not working from local react app

Tags: firebase, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am trying to setup a chatbot in local app (Local app developed using react, please find the more details on reference link). Below the steps what i have done.

1. Created dialogflow agent and few intents in developer account.
2. Enabled fulfillment and deployed in firebase using Dialogflow webhook inline editor.

While testing this in dialog flow console online, it is working fine with proper fulfillment response.

But while trying the same intent query with fulfillment in local app it is not working.

I am not sure whether firebase or dialogflow fulfillment services will not be allowed freely from outside of dialog flow console. Or am i missing something ?

Please guide me to test it in local.

Also, Do i have any restrictions and guidelines for developing and hosting fulfillment in our servers.

**Reference**
https://pusher.com/tutorials/weather-chatbot-react-dialogflow

Comment: While debugin this issue using Dialog flow debug logs, found this issue occurs due to Pusher configuration in local app and currently it works fine. Thanks all.

Comment: If you've solved your problem, you can post this as an answer to the question. This way other people who have similar problems may be helped by your question and answer.